# Wordpress - Adding a post category box to custom post type

Tags: wordpress

I have created a custom post type called 'Case Studies' ... What i want to be able to do is display the box with the categories of normal posts inside the Case Studies 'add case study page', so i can choose posts that are associated with the case study im making.

All this done in the admin section.

Any suggestions would be great.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

In your `register_post_type` function's arguments array parameter, add the following key and array value to add the regular categories in the custom post type add/edit page:

`'taxonomies' => array("category")`

For example:

```
register_post_type( 'slider',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
        'name' => _x( 'Slider', 'post type general name' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Slider', 'post type singular name' ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'Slider' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Slider' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Slider' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'New Slider' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'View Slider' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search Slider' ),
        'not_found' =>  __( 'No Slider Items found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Slider Items found in Trash' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    ),
        'public' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
        'supports' => array('title','thumbnail'),
        'taxonomies' => array("category"),   /* This is what you are looking for and the value has to be an array. */
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
    )
);
```

For details see the [Wordpress register_post_type function documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type).

Answer (score 1):

try this or check this [tutorial](http://goo.gl/lyt7ff)

```
function Book() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'               => 'Books',
    'singular_name'      => 'Book',
    'add_new'            => 'Add New',
    'add_new_item'       => 'Add New Book',
    'edit_item'          => 'Edit Book',
    'new_item'           => 'New Book',
    'all_items'          => 'All Books',
    'view_item'          => 'View Book',
    'search_items'       => 'Search Books',
    'not_found'          => 'No books found',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No books found in Trash',
    'parent_item_colon'  => '',
    'menu_name'          => 'Books'
  );

  $args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'book' ),
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'menu_position'      => null,
    'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
    'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag')
  );

  register_post_type( 'book', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'book' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Ohh, interesting. Not that i have done this before but i just thinking of it makes it exciting. I do things a little dirty so forgive me.

I would a special tag to my custom post. Then add a second loop to my custom post that would query posts based on that tag.

Comment: But with using tags, would it be able to get the URL for that post? ... Im completely stumped how to even try to do this

Comment: You have to remember that as long as you can get those posts in that loop. You can always get the information on that post e.g title, content etc. I think it's worth a try, i did something a little similar but i wanted to show other custom posts types on the page like other projects.

Comment: Is there any chance you could post some example code .... im a bit new to this. :)

Comment: Have a look at this page. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts There are some ideas